# How do I add in input a list of objects with their own attributes in thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm sorry for how i've written my question but I can't really explain my problem with a question.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Form Persona</title>
    </head>
<body>
<h1>Aggiungi una persona</h1>

<form th:action="@{/persona}" method="POST" th:object="${persona}">
    <div th:if="${#fields.hasGlobalErrors()}">
        <p th:each="err : ${#fields.globalErrors()}" th:text="${err}">...</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>Nome:</span>
        <span><input type="text" th:field="*{nome}"/></span>
        <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('nome')}" th:errors="*{nome}"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>Cognome:</span>
        <span><input type="text" th:field="*{cognome}"/></span>
        <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('cognome')}" th:errors="*{cognome}"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>Età:</span>
        <span><input type="text" th:field="*{eta}"/></span>
        <span th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('eta')}" th:errors="*{eta}"></span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span><button type="submit">Conferma</button></span>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the code I'm using in springBoot with thymeleaf to add a new person,

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.validation.constraints.Max;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Entity
public class Persona {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   private Long id;

   @NotBlank
   private String nome;

   @NotBlank
   private String cognome;

   @NotNull
   @Min(0)
   @Max(120)
   private Integer eta;

   public String getNome() {
       return nome;
   }

   public void setNome(String nome) {
       this.nome = nome;
   }

   public String getCognome() {
       return cognome;
   }

   public void setCognome(String cognome) {
       this.cognome = cognome;
   }

   public Integer getEta() {
       return eta;
   }

   public void setEta(Integer eta) {
       this.eta = eta;
   }

   public Long getId() {
       return id;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object obj) {
       Persona persona = (Persona)obj;
       return this.nome.equals(persona.nome) && 
               this.cognome.equals(persona.cognome) &&
               this.eta.equals(persona.eta);
   }
}
```

And this is the Person class.

Now I want to add a new attribute to the Person class: `List<Child> children`. Every child has a name and a surname. How do I add it to my thymeleaf code?
Thank you for helping, if you need me to post more of my code, tell me

Comment: I am not sure what you are specifically asking or trying to do - or where you are stuck - but here are some notes: (1) What is stopping you from adding `List<Child> children` to your `Persona` class? (2) Work backwards from the HTML you want to end up with. What does that look like? What structure does it have for a person's list of children? (3) In Thymeleaf you can [iterate over collections](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#iteration).

Comment: I'm stuck because I dont know how to add it in my thymeleaf code. Now if i go in my localhost i can add a new person just by writing his name, his surname and his age, but how can i do it if the person has children? The children class has attribute itself.